# Read from file (C++)

Tags: c++, iostream, readfile

I can't figure out why this won't read from my file...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int acctNum;
    int checks;
    double interest;
    double acctBal;
    double monthlyFee;
    const int COL_SZ = 3;
    ifstream fileIn;
    fileIn.open("BankAccounts.txt");
    if(fileIn.fail())
    {
        cout << "File couldn't open." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << left;
        cout << "Bank Account records:" << endl;
        cout << setw(COL_SZ) << "Account#" << setw(COL_SZ) <<
            "Balance" << setw(COL_SZ) << "Interest" << setw(COL_SZ) << "Monthly Fee" << setw(COL_SZ) <<
            "Allowed Checks" << setw(COL_SZ) << endl;
        while(fileIn >> acctNum >> acctBal >> interest >> monthlyFee >> checks)
        {
            cout << setw(COL_SZ) << acctNum << setw(COL_SZ) << acctBal << setw(COL_SZ) << interest << setw(COL_SZ) <<
                monthlyFee << setw(COL_SZ) << checks << endl;
        }
    }
    fileIn.close();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

**I took out the ios::out and put in ios::in same thing happened no data and the same thing with taking ios out all together.** I did make the file from a previous program...would i have to put the reading of the files code into that program?

[image: The BankAccount.txt file as a picture.]

Comment: Shouldn't you open the input file with ifstream::in flag instead of out?

Comment: +1 For the cool looking browser. (Joking. :) )

Comment: Woulda been nice to get a point for at least having a cool browser T_T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**

Looking at your input you can't read such complex input with just

```
while(fileIn >> acctNum >> acctBal >> monthlyFee >> checks)
```

This code is setup to read data formatted in the following form:

```
11 12.12 11.11 13.13 14.12
11 12.12 11.11 13.13 14.12
11 12.12 11.11 13.13 14.12
```

Instead you'll have to read the various strings and such before scraping out the data you need. For example to skip over the word "Account" below, you can read it into a dummy string

```
Account Number#1234
```

```
 std::string dummy; 
 fileIn >> dummy;   // read up to the whitespace, 
                    // in this case reads in the word "Account"
```

Then To get the number you'll have to read the next string and extract the #1234

```
 std::string temp; 
 fileIn >> temp;   // read up to the whitespace, 
                    // in this case reads in the word "Number#1234"
```

But you could also use [getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/) to read up to and including the #

```
 std::getline(fileIn, dummy, '#');
```

Then read in the number after the #

```
 int acctNum = 0;
 fileIn >> acctNum;
```

So if you're input is truly formatted as you describe, you'll have to spend a lot more time figuring out how to parse your data then you may have expected. I don't know enough about how your input is expected to give you a complete answer, but the above should hopefully get you started.

(Optionally, you could learn about regular expressions, but at this point you may just want to learn the basics.)

**Original**

I just tried your code out and with enough well-formatted values in the input, it works in g++. However, one thing that I am wary of looking at your code is this line:

```
   while(fileIn >> acctNum >> acctBal >> monthlyFee >> checks)
```

If any of the above fails to read due to the file ending prematurely, your cout isn't going to get executed, causing no output to the screen. Does your input have all the above values? Are they well formatted? To debug I might try breaking up the reads:

```
   while (fileIn)
   {
       fileIn >> acctNum;
       std::cout << "Acct num is:" << acctNum << std::endl;
       ...
   }
```

or just step through with a debugger.

For example for this input:

> 11  12.12 11.11 13.13 14.12

your code prints out

```
Bank Account records:   
Account#BalanceInterestMonthly FeeAllowed Checks   
11 12.126.93517e-31011.1113 `
```

But screwing with the input and adding a random non numeric character somewhere, ie:

> 11 * 12.12 11.11 13.13 14.12

causes me to get just

```
Bank Account records:     
Account#BalanceInterestMonthly FeeAllowed Checks
```

So I would definitely look piece-by-piece at what's getting read and where a read from `fileIn` is failing, this would definitely cause your problems.

You know of course to remove the `ios::out` as specified [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ifstream/ifstream/)

Comment: Yeah my text file looks pretty....choppy when I open it... how can I format this better? and do I ahve to format it perfectly for it to be able to read my file?

Comment: @Alex as long as there's whitespace between the numerical inputs and there's enough inputs, then this should work. However if your input doesn't follow this standard, it might fail right away causing you to see what you see.

Comment: @Alex, I can see you're having the problem I described. See my updated answer for what might help you start to figure out how to parse that input.

Comment: Thanks, My book isn't very helpful when it comes to things like this -.-; i think ill just re-enter the input to be more....uniform.

Comment: I finished it and it works. I cheated and just entered in the numbers manually >.>;;

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
fileIn.open("BankAccounts.txt", ios::out);
                                ^^^^^^^^
```

You're opening the file for output. Try ios::in.